# Class with virtual function, when derived from QObject, leads to linking error

Tags: c++, qt, linker, ld

Following is the code that works fine

```c
class HttpService {
public:
    virtual ~HttpService(); // implemented in .cpp
protected:
    HttpService(struct MHD_Connection *conn) {}
};
class HttpFileService : public HttpService
{
public:
    virtual ~HttpFileService() ; // implemented in .cpp
protected:
    HttpFileService(struct MHD_Connection *conn) : HttpService(conn) {}
};
```

Now, when I make `HttpService` a derived class of `QObject`, like below:

```c
#include <QObject>                      // change #1
class HttpService  : public QObject {   // change #2
    Q_OBJECT                            // change #3
public:
    virtual ~HttpService();
protected:
    HttpService(struct MHD_Connection *conn) {}
};

class HttpFileService : public HttpService {
    Q_OBJECT                            // change #4
public:
    virtual ~HttpFileService() ;
protected:
    HttpFileService(struct MHD_Connection *conn) : HttpService(conn) {}
};
```

I encounter the following linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for HttpService", referenced from:
      HttpService::~HttpService()in httpservice.o
```

Changing `HttpService`'s constructor to the following doesn't help either

```
explicit HttpService(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
```

Comment: `~HttpService()` is still implemented in `.cpp` file after the code change ? I am asking this because, in the changed code, I don't see the comment as `// implemented in .cpp`.

Comment: @iammilind, Yes it still is. The only lines that were changed are highlighted in the comments

Comment: Is that the whole of `HttpService()`? I often see this error if I declare a virtual function in an abstract base class, and forget to make it pure. (gcc generates the vtable in the same object file as the first non-pure, non-inline virtual function, if such a function is declared, and if that doesn't have a definition then it will end up missing).

Comment: @mike-seymour, Good point! This is indeed not the entire class, but I double checked and what you said does not seem to be the case here. Also, why would the code not break prior to deriving it from QObject?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Force running qmake and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking to the correct qt libraries?

Comment: Yes, There are other QObject-derived classes in my project which are going through just fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the moc-compiler? If not, remove the Q_OBJECT macros! And do you include / link the results from the moc-compilation?