# QObject: Missing vtable link error

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals, moc

I know the question have been asked tons of times but I can't find the solution here nor in google.

Here's my header file

```
#ifndef MAINCONTROLLER_H
#define MAINCONTROLLER_H

#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QObject>

#include "PhTools/PhString.h"
#include "PhStrip/PhStripDoc.h"

class MainController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainController(QObject *parent = 0);
    void loadSettings();
    PhString getLastFile();
    void setLastFile(PhString fileName);
    bool openDoc(PhString fileName);

signals:
    void docChanged();

private:
    QSettings * _settings;
    PhStripDoc * _doc;

};

#endif // MAINCONTROLLER_H
```

And my CPP file :

```
#include "MainController.h"


MainController::MainController(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    _doc = new PhStripDoc();
    loadSettings();
}
void MainController::loadSettings()
{
    _settings = new QSettings(QDir::homePath() + "/Library/Preferences/com.me.me.plist", QSettings::NativeFormat);

    getLastFile();
}

PhString MainController::getLastFile()
{
    qDebug() << "lastfile :" << _settings->value("last_file", "").toString();
    return _settings->value("last_file").toString();
}

bool MainController::openDoc(PhString fileName)
{
    bool succeed = _doc->openDX(fileName);
    if (succeed)
        emit docChanged();
    return succeed;
}

void MainController::setLastFile(PhString filename)
{
    _settings->setValue("last_file", filename);
}
```

And here's the error log :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MainController::docChanged()", referenced from:
      MainController::openDoc(QString) in MainController.o
  "vtable for MainController", referenced from:
      MainController::MainController(QObject*) in MainController.o
      MainController::MainController(QObject*) in MainController.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It might come from `signals` but I'm not sure...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class with virtual function, when derived from QObject, leads to linking error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103964/class-with-virtual-function-when-derived-from-qobject-leads-to-linking-error)

Comment: (There are several others duplicates)

Comment: @MatsPetersson : Nice. The _"solution"_ you linked with solve **nothing** for me. But thank you anyway, now I'm stuck. Furthermore, I **need** QObject to use signals.

Comment: In a comment to this answer, it says that editing the `.pro` file helped solve the problem (and running qmake):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774291/q-object-throwing-undefined-reference-to-vtable-error

Comment: unfortunately my `.pro` fil is already with `Qt += gui` and running qmake don't change

Comment: Is it possible that the `docChanged` error is causing the type to be incomplete -> no class generated -> no vtable?

Comment: @MatsPetersson : `docChanged()` is a signal and have no implementation, this kind of structure is already working on other projects I'm working with and that's why I don't understand the issue

Comment: Surely the compiler shouldn't complain about it tho'. So somethijng is wrong there too.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I solved it with the MOC solution, I might was a little tired yesterday. Thank you! (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4774338/2307070)

Comment: As said in the last comment, I've solved it but not with you method, that's why I can't accept yours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include this line at the end of your source file:

`#include "MainController.moc"`

Alternatively, you can also handle this with your buildsystem, but that is probably the former is easier.

Answer (score 14):

When the `Q_OBJECT` macro is added after the code has already been compiled, `qmake` has to be run again. This will add the creation and compilation of `MainController.moc` to your `Makefile` thus preventing the linker error.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem after I added the `Q_OBJECT` macro. Right click your project and click **Run qmake** then try building again.